# ajax get geolocation json data from smart-ip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to get user's geolocation by smart-ip service. It is very simple: I open the http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json from browser, then I can get the data. Now I want to do it through ajax:

```
    $('.image-widget-data input[type="file"]').click(function(){
    $.get('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json',function(data){
            console.debug(data);
        },'json');
});
```

This function is called, but I can not get any data, please check the following link to see the response in firebug.

[image]

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code, and it seems that you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you add to your code a fail handler, you will see your error:

```
$('.image-widget-data input[type="file"]').click(function(){
    $.get('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json',function(data){
        console.debug(data);
    },'json').fail(function(data){console.log(data)});
});
```

I don't know wether the service you are calling support JSONP, but you can use 
the **freegeoip** service to do that:

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
    console.log(location);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are violating Same Origin Policy of browser.

You should look into JSONP request. `smart-ip` does support JSONP.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api).

Example: http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/11.22.33.44?callback=_function_name_